# why is html content not displayed in email with attachments

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, html-email, email-attachments

I am using JavaMail to send E-mails with html content and attachments. But when sending an E-mail containing both html content and attachments, the html content is diplayed as plain text.

I have set the `Content-Type` headers as `text/html; charset=us-ascii` but in the E-mail I receive, the `Content-Type` is shown as `text/plain`. Why is this happening?

Here's my code:

```
if(f!=null){ // f is an array containing the attachment file objects
                Multipart mp=new MimeMultipart("mixed");
                BodyPart mbody=new MimeBodyPart();
                mbody.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=us-ascii");
                mbody.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding","7bit");
                mbody.setText(content);                               
                mp.addBodyPart(mbody);                                        
                for(File file:f){    
                    BodyPart mbody2=new MimeBodyPart();
                    DataSource ds=new FileDataSource(file.getAbsolutePath());
                    mbody2.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(ds));
                    mbody2.setFileName(ds.getName());
                    System.out.println(ds.getName());
                    mbody2.setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/mixed");
                    mp.addBodyPart(mbody2);                        
                }
                m.setContent(mp);
                //m.setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/mixed");
                //m.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding","base64");
            }
            else{
                m.setContent(content,"text/html");
                m.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=us-ascii");
                m.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding","7bit");
            }
            m.saveChanges();
```

If I uncomment `m.setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/mixed");`, then the attachment(s) are displayed as noname without an extension and the content isn't present at all.

If I send the E-mail without attachments, the html content is displayed properly.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

Need to put `mbody.setContent(content, "text/html");` instead of `mbody.setText(content);`.

Comment: Or declare mbody as MimeBodyPart and use mbody.setText(content, "utf-8", "html");